# ColdFusion uploadall, upload multiple files, AJAX, insert into MySQL table

Tags: html, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm relatively a novice in ColdFusion. I'm trying to upload multiple files into a MySQL DB. Unfortunately only one file is inserting instead of multiple.  How can I insert multiple files? 
Would I need to enclose my DB insert in cfloop?
Here is my code.....

This is the HTML portion. I'm also using bootstrap-fileinput

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="file-loading">                      
        <input name="buttonAction" type="file" value="Upload File" 
          title="Upload File" id="UploadFile" data-browse-on-zone-click="true" 
          accept=".pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx,.pptx,.xls,.xlsx, .rtf, .msg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.tiff" multiple> 
        </input><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the upload click event on my form...

```
        $("#UploadFile").click(function() {

            $('#UploadFile').fileinput('upload');
            var model_data = $("#frmIssue").serializeArray();
            $.each(model_data,function(key,input)
            {
                formData.append(input.name,input.value);
            });

             for (var value of formData.values()) {
                console.log(value); 
                }   

            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmIssue"));

            $.ajax({
                    url: 'FileUtility.cfc?method=uploadFiles&fkIssueId=#tmpIssueUUID#&fkUserId=#me.getId()#',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false
            }).done(function(response){
                    document.getElementById('thisAttachment').value="";
                    $('#results').empty();
                    $('#results').load('<cfoutput>#root#</cfoutput>page.viewattachments',{'tmpIssueID':'<cfoutput>#tmpIssueUUID#</cfoutput>','pid':'<cfoutput>#URL.pid#</cfoutput>'});
                    //alert("Attachment loaded successfully.");
                    $('#alertModalTitle').html('Attachment loaded successfully.');
                    $('#alertModalBody').html('All attachments are listed below');
                    $('#alertModalFooter').html('');
                    $('#alertModal').modal('show');

            }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorMessage){
                    $('#results').empty();
                    $('#results').html(errorMessage);
                    //alert("Attachment unsuccessful.\n"+errorMessage);
                    $('#alertModalTitle').html('Attachment error:');
                    $('#alertModalBody').html(errorMessage);
                    $('#alertModalFooter').html('');
                    $('#alertModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

My AJAX call is made to this function in the FileUtility.cfc file, written in ColdFusion...

```
<cffunction name="uploadFiles" access="remote" output="false" returntype="String">
        <cfargument name="fkIssueId" type="string" required="true" default="" />
        <cfargument name="fkUserId" type="string" required="true" default="" />

        <cfset var mypath = "" />       
        <cfset var mydirectory = "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\MyApp\attachments" />     
        <cfset var mypathtemp = "" />
        <cfset var newfile = "" />
        <cfset var newfilename = "" />
        <cfset var newfileext = "" />
        <cfset var strOriginalFile = "" />
        <cfset var strOriginalFileExt = "" />
        <cfset var strOriginalFileName = "" />
        <cfset var strUploadedNewFile = "" />
        <cfset var strUploadedNewFileExt = "" />
        <cfset var strUploadedNewFileName = "" />

        <cfset mypath = #mydirectory# & "\" & #arguments.fkIssueId# & "\"  />
        <cfif NOT directoryExists("#mypath#")>
            <cfdirectory directory="#mypath#" action="create" />
        </cfif>

        <cfset mypathtemp = #mydirectory# & "\" & #arguments.fkIssueId#  & "\" & #arguments.fkUserId# & "\"  />
        <cfif NOT directoryExists("#mypathtemp#")>
            <cfdirectory directory="#mypathtemp#" action="create" />
        </cfif>

        <cffile action="uploadall" destination="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#" nameconflict="makeunique" result="myupload" />
        <cfset str.STATUS = 200 />
        <cfset str.Message = "Passed" />
        <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(str)#</cfoutput>


        <cfset strUploadedNewFileExt = myupload[1].ServerFileExt>
        <cfset strUploadedNewFile = getCleanedUpFile(file=myupload[1].ServerFile) />
        <cffile action="rename" source="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#myupload[1].ServerFile#" destination="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#strUploadedNewFile#" />

        <cfset strUploadedNewFileName = #reverse(listRest(reverse(strUploadedNewFile),"."))#>
        <cfset bdoesExist = #doesFileNameExist(fkIssueId=arguments.fkIssueId,file=strUploadedNewFile)#>

        <cfif #doesFileNameExist(fkIssueId=arguments.fkIssueId,file=strUploadedNewFile)# gt 0>
            <cfset iFileName = getFileName(file=strUploadedNewFile,fkIssueId=arguments.fkIssueId) />
            <cfset iFile = getFile(file=strUploadedNewFile,fkIssueId=arguments.fkIssueId) />

            <cfset strOriginalFileExt = #strUploadedNewFileExt# />
            <cfset strOriginalFile = #strUploadedNewFile# />
            <cfset strOriginalFileName = #strUploadedNewFileName# />

            <cfset iTotalCount = getFileCount(file=iFile,fkIssueId=arguments.fkIssueId) />

            <cfif #iTotalCount#>
                <cfset newCount = #iTotalCount# + 1>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset newCount = 1>
            </cfif>

            <cfset newfile = "#iFileName#_V#NumberFormat(newcount,'0000')#.#strOriginalFileExt#">
            <cfset newfilename = "#iFileName#_V#NumberFormat(newcount,'0000')#">
            <cfset newfileext = #strUploadedNewFileExt#>

            <cffile action="rename" source="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#strUploadedNewFile#" destination="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#newfile#" />
            <cffile action="move" source="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#newfile#" destination="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#newfile#" />

            <cfdirectory directory="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#" action="delete" />

            <cfset strOriginalFile = iFile />
            <cfset strOriginalFileName = iFileName />

        <cfelse>
            <cfset strOriginalFile = #strUploadedNewFile#>
            <cfset strOriginalFileExt = #strUploadedNewFileExt#>
            <cfset strOriginalFileName = #strUploadedNewFileName#>
            <cfset newfile = #strUploadedNewFile#>
            <cfset newfilename = #strUploadedNewFileName#>
            <cfset newfileext = #strUploadedNewFileExt#>
            <cffile action="move" source="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#\#newfile#" destination="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#newfile#" />
            <cfdirectory directory="#mydirectory#\#arguments.fkIssueId#\#arguments.fkUserId#" action="delete" />

        </cfif>

        <cfquery>
            INSERT INTO tbl_attachments
            (
                id,
                Attachment,
                AttachmentName,
                AttachmentExt,
                OrigAttachment,
                OrigAttachmentName,
                fkIssueId,
                final,
                fkUserId,
                Dateuploaded
                )
            VALUES (
                '#CreateUUID()#',
                '#newfile#',
                '#newfilename#',
                '#newfileext#',
                '#strOriginalFile#',
                '#strOriginalFileName#',
                '#arguments.fkIssueId#',
                0,
                '#arguments.fkUserId#',
                #createodbcdatetime(now())#
                )
        </cfquery>
    </cffunction>
```

Thank you in advanced....

Comment: Make sure you are using `<cfqueryparam>` in your query inputs.

Comment: What makes you conclude the files weren't uploaded? Did you test the cffunction without ajax? If not, you do that first... Debugging server side problems with ajax is slow and painful

Comment: I tried to upload 3 files at the same time. The 3 files did make it to the server side location. However, based on my DB insert only one filename was inserted.

Comment: It's probably because cffile action=uploadAll returns any *array* of files. So the physical files were uploaded, but the later code only inserts the first file, i.e.`myUpload[1]...`, into the database.  You need to loop through the array of results and  insert each file  name individually.

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but since you mentioned being new to CF, I'd highly recommend reading up on the importance of protecting your database queries against [sql injection](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Security/item/Injection) and [securing file uploads](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Security/item/File_Uploads/).

Comment: Also, what's the reasoning behind the file renaming convention? Just wondering if there's a way to simplify some of the code...

Comment: @Agreax is correct here - action="uploadAll" returns an array of files - if you want to handle them all then you will need to loop through that array, as per the Adobe docs: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-uploadall.html

Comment: Arrgggg!....I don't know why I didn't see this at first. I totally missed that myupload is an array. Dammit! Thanks, I'm quite sure I can solve this issue now.  Thank you @Agreax and SevRoberts. Greatly appreciate the help. I'll report back with the result.